# How to select rows from another table based on a table containing min and max values

Tags: sql, max, min

**TableA**:

```
Userid sessionid domain_value tag
---------------------------------
1       20      amex      bank
1       40      visa      bank
2       10      citibank  bank
2       20      amex      bank
2       30      amex      bank
```

**TableB**:

```
Userid sessionid(min) sessionid(max)
------------------------------------
1      20             40
2      10             30  
3
4
5
```

How to retrieve all the rows from TableA based on values in TableB?

```
select * 
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.userid = b.userid
where a.sessionid between (select b.[sessionid(min)] from TableB b) 
                      and (select b.sessionid(max)] from TableB b)
```

Comment: i'm not sure why you need to get min and max based on what you want.

Comment: for session grouping from min and max as 1 block

Comment: Your main issue is your unrelated subqueries. `(select b.[sessionid(min)] from TableB b)` retrieves *all* `[sessionid(min)]` from `tableB`, while you already have a `tableB` row joined to the `tableA` row the values of which you should consider instead. See scaisEdge's answer on this. As you want to select rows from `tableA` only, however, I would not even join at all. Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

assumin  table B  with these column name

```
Userid, sessionid_min, sessionid_max,
```

try using  just `between column_fom_min and column_for_max`

```
select * 
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.userid = b.userid
where a.sessionid between b.sessionid_min
                      and  b.sessionid_max
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to retrieve all the rows from TableA based on values in TableB?

In order to retrieve rows from `TableA`, select from `TableA`. If you want to filter based on values in `TableB`, place an according `WHERE`clause in the query. There is no need to join here.

```
select *
from tablea a
where exists
(
  select null
  from tableb b
  where a.sessionid between b.sessionid_min and b.sessionid_max
)
order by userid, sessionid;
```

(You can achieve the same with a join, but the intention would not be as clear from reading the query.)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
 select t.Userid , 
     (select min(sessionid) from TableA as tb on tb.Userid =t.Userid ) as Min,
     (select max(sessionid) from TableA as tb on tb.Userid =t.Userid ) as Max 
 from TableA as t group by t.Userid
```

Comment: What? I guess you were still a little sleepy when writing this answer ;-) Your query is an over-complicated (and slightly invalid) version of a mere `select userid, min(sessionid), max(sessionid) from tablea group by userid`. And you misunderstood the OP it seems. `TableB` is an existing table, not a query result.